# Parse: How do I get data from Parse that will be displayed in different unique view controllers

Tags: swift, parse-platform

So lets say there is a tableview and within that tableview each cell title and subtitle is loaded from Parse. How would I to make it so that once a cell is tapped and opened, it loads a view controller that has a navigation bar, picture, and text that is unique to that one cell. Each cell would have different text, pictures, and navigation bars, in which that data is loaded from Parse. Can pictures be stored on Parse and retrieved in-app?

I am working in swift. Feel free to ask me for any additional information. Thank you for your time! I appreciate any help!

Comment: this is a code request not a question ! update your question and add your problem ;)

Comment: @Mojtabye updated. better?

Comment: is your problem about custom cells with image,title and description or about parse storage and how to load image ?!

Comment: @Mojtabye it is about Parse storage and how to load text/images using one view controller for multiple cells. is it possible to do that?

Comment: take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21846077/how-to-load-an-image-from-parse-into-a-uiimageview-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each individual cell will display the information related to one specific parse object, set it up so that your detail view controller has a parse object property and then when the user clicks a cell in the first view controller (the table), pass the parse object associated with that cell in prepareForSegue by setting the second view controller's parse object property to that specific object. By doing that, you can access all of that parse object's information in the second view controller through that property.

If the above is not the case, just make sure your second view controller has whatever properties it'll need so the relevant information needed to query Parse for whatever data you're trying to display can be accessed from your detail view controller.