# Parse: Retrieving Data by Row

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform

Overview: How can I make it so that when the cell with the segue
 identifier of 0 will load data in the row that has 0 as its ID, cell with segue identifier of 1 will load data in the row that has 1 as its ID, and so on and so forth. The data includes ID (responds to cell identifier), navTitle (title of the navigation bar), written (who the article was written by), date (date of the article), and article (the article itself).

[image]

I am trying to make it so that once a cell is tapped in my tableview it opens data unique to that cell. What would the best way to do that? I was thinking that maybe I should have it check the ID column I have on Parse and load data the data in that row, but I'm not sure how to do that. Is there a better way to do this? Any help is appreciated! Feel free to ask me for any additional information.

[image]

^ So here I have a tableview in which data is being taken from Parse and used for both labels.

[image]

^ This view controller is segued to the cell above with:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("0a", sender: nil)
        self.tableview.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    }
}
```

Here is my **EventsDetailViewController**, the one that is called when a cell is tapped:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI
import Bolts

class EventDetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func eventDetail(sender: AnyObject) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}

@IBOutlet weak var articleTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var writtenBy: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var date: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var article: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var navBar: UINavigationBar!

var dateDetail = [String]()
var articleDetail = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadEvents()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func loadEvents () -> Void {

    var query = PFQuery(className: "eventsdetail")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error : NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            if let objects = objects as [PFObject]! {
                for object in objects {

                    var output1 = object.objectForKey("navTitle") as! String
                    self.navBar.topItem?.title = output1

                    var output2 = object.objectForKey("articleTitle") as! String
                    self.articleTitle.text = output2

                    var output3 = object.objectForKey("written") as! String
                    self.writtenBy.text = output3

                    var output4 = object.objectForKey("date") as! String
                    self.date.text = output4

                    var output5 = object.objectForKey("article") as! String
                    self.article.text = output5

                }
            }

        }

    }
}

}
```

Here is my **EventsViewController**:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import Bolts
import ParseUI

class EventsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var timer: NSTimer!
var isAnimating = false
var currentColorIndex = 0
var currentLabelIndex = 0
var customView: UIView!
var labelsArray: Array<UILabel> = []
var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl!
var testArray = [String]()
var subArray = [String]()

@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!


@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

    tableview.delegate = self
    tableview.dataSource = self

    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: Selector("loadEvents"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.tableview.addSubview(refreshControl)
    loadEvents()

    loadCustomRefreshContents()

    //refreshControl colors
    refreshControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor() //color of background
    refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor() //color of indicator
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func loadEvents () -> Void {

    testArray = [String]()
    subArray = [String]()

    let query = PFQuery(className: "events")
    let runkey = query.orderByDescending("eventTitle")
    runkey.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {


            if let objects = objects as [PFObject]! {
                for object in objects {

                    let load = object.objectForKey("eventTitle") as! String
                    self.testArray.append(load)

                    let subload = object.objectForKey("date") as! String
                    self.subArray.append(subload)

                    //reload TableView
                    self.tableview.reloadData()
                    print(self.testArray)
                }

            }
        } else {

            print("error:\(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }

    }

    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}

func do_table_refresh() {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        self.tableview.reloadData()
        return

    }

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("0a", sender: nil)
        self.tableview.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    }
}

func tableView(tableView:UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int {
    return testArray.count
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("eventcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EventTableViewCell
    cell.title.text = self.testArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.subTitle.text = self.subArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

//refreshes tableview; starts refresh
func loadCustomRefreshContents() {
    let refreshContents = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("RefreshControl", owner: self, options: nil)

    customView = refreshContents[0] as! UIView
    customView.frame = refreshControl.bounds

    for var i=0; i<customView.subviews.count; ++i {
        labelsArray.append(customView.viewWithTag(i + 1) as! UILabel)
    }

    refreshControl.addSubview(customView)


}

//stops refresh
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    do_table_refresh()

    if refreshControl.refreshing {
        if !isAnimating {
            animateRefreshStep1()

        }
    }
}

//cycles through colors
func getNextColor() -> UIColor {
    var colorsArray: Array<UIColor> = [UIColor.magentaColor(), UIColor.brownColor(), UIColor.yellowColor(), UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.orangeColor()]

    if currentColorIndex == colorsArray.count {
        currentColorIndex = 0
    }

    let returnColor = colorsArray[currentColorIndex]
    ++currentColorIndex

    return returnColor
}

func doSomething() {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4.0, target: self, selector: "endOfWork", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    self.do_table_refresh()

}

func endOfWork() {
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()

    timer.invalidate()
    timer = nil
}

//first part of animation
func animateRefreshStep1() {
    isAnimating = true

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.labelsArray[self.currentLabelIndex].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_4))
        self.labelsArray[self.currentLabelIndex].textColor = self.getNextColor()

        }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.05, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.labelsArray[self.currentLabelIndex].transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                self.labelsArray[self.currentLabelIndex].textColor = UIColor.blackColor()

                }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
                    ++self.currentLabelIndex

                    if self.currentLabelIndex < self.labelsArray.count {
                        self.animateRefreshStep1()
                    }
                    else {
                        self.animateRefreshStep2()
                    }
            })
    })
}

//second part of animation
func animateRefreshStep2() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.35, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.labelsArray[0].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)
        self.labelsArray[1].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)
        self.labelsArray[2].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)
        self.labelsArray[3].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)
        self.labelsArray[4].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)
        self.labelsArray[5].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)
        self.labelsArray[6].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)
        self.labelsArray[7].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)
        self.labelsArray[8].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)
        self.labelsArray[9].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)

        }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.labelsArray[0].transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                self.labelsArray[1].transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                self.labelsArray[2].transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                self.labelsArray[3].transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                self.labelsArray[4].transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                self.labelsArray[5].transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                self.labelsArray[6].transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                self.labelsArray[7].transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                self.labelsArray[8].transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                self.labelsArray[9].transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

                }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
                    if self.refreshControl.refreshing {
                        self.currentLabelIndex = 0
                        self.animateRefreshStep1()
                    }
                    else {
                        self.isAnimating = false
                        self.currentLabelIndex = 0
                        for var i=0; i<self.labelsArray.count; ++i {
                            self.labelsArray[i].textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                            self.labelsArray[i].transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                        }
                    }
            })
    })
}

}
```

Comment: please change screenshot with the code for the actual code.

Comment: Fetch the entire object using the objectID. How are you populating the tableview controller ? I assume fetching all the objects ? Then you already have all data you need. Just pass the parse object to the next view controller and fill out that second screen.

Comment: @DogCoffee I'm populating the tableviewcontroller with Parse, using a separate class called events. I have another class called eventsdetail which holds all the data for the detailviewcontroller. How would I pass it on? Fill out the second screen of what?

Comment: Tableview data source should already be holding each PFObject. Just pass that object to the second view controller when you select that cell. Thats what your asking right ? "once a cell is tapped in my tableview it opens data unique to that cell"

Comment: @DogCoffee that's not quite what I'm looking for. if you take a look at the 1st picture, there is a title, date, written by, and article. I want to be able to have the row on Parse with the ID of 0 to be retrieved when the cell with the segue identifier 0 is tapped, same as if cell had an identifier of 1, it would get the data from the row with the ID of 1. hopefully that made sense.

Comment: Please do not repost questions. You have asked this multiple times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse: How do I get data from Parse that will be displayed in different unique view controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466518/parse-how-do-i-get-data-from-parse-that-will-be-displayed-in-different-unique-v)

Comment: Sort the data in the the tableview data source array to your desired format (in your case ID)  - then reload the tableview - then when you select the row in the tableview you pass the data across - using the tableview indexPath.row - which is correspond to the tableview data source - using prepare for segue you pass that PFObject to the next view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the data on the tableView just make sure you create a segue in your storyboard connecting the prototype cell and the destination view controller and add an identifier to the segue.

Next, on the controller with the tableView make sure you call:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "segueIdentifier"){

        let detailScene = segue.destinationViewController as! EventDetailViewController

        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let row = Int(indexPath.row)

            //here you can pass all the data to the destination viewController. But you CANT POPULATE YOUR LABELS. make sure you pass the data to some auxiliar variable(s). Next line is an example
            detailScene.selectedData = (self.myData[row] as! PFObject)
        }
    }
}
```

Update:

```
detailScene.selectedData = (self.myData[row] as! PFObject)
```

`detailScene` is an instance of the destination viewController. `selectedData` is, in this case an instance of PFObject that will be use to populate the labels in my destination viewController. `self.myData` is an array in my source viewController with the data that is shown in my tableView.

So if you want to send the data you show in your cells. (

```
self.testArray[indexPath.row]
self.subArray[indexPath.row]
```

) make sure you declare the variables that will receive this data on your `EventsDetailViewController` something like this:

```
var testString:String!
var subString:String!
```

Then in your prepareForSegue (`EventsViewController`) make sure to instantiate this variables with the proper data:

```
detailScene.test = self.testArray[row]
detailScene.sub = self.subArray[row]
```

Finally on `EventsDetailViewController` you can pass the data to the labels you want on `viewDidLoad()`:

```
self.articleTitle.text = testString
```

Let me know in case of any concerns.

Comment: could you elaborate for me on the `detailScene.selectedData = (self.myData[row] as! PFObject)` I'm confused about it.

Comment: it says 'eventdetailviewcontroller' has no member 'selectedData'

Comment: you should create the variables in your EventDetailViewController to send the data from the controller with the tableView to the EventDetailViewController.

Comment: on the line `detailScene.selectedData = (self.myData[row] as! PFObject)` it gives me an error saying: **Cannot assign to value: function call returns immutable value**

Comment: @Hunter Updated the question with more details

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is the archetypical basic app: show a list of items in a tableview and being able to tap on a row to see more details.

What seems unusual to me is how you have two different classes: events and eventdetails.

Compare it with a database of books. You would not have a Book class and a BookDetails class. You would only have a Book class that contains all details about a book. So when you want to show a list of books, you fetch all the Book objects. In the tableviewcontroller you display a subset of fields from the Book objects (like i.e. title and author). When the user then taps on a specific book, you open a viewcontroller and pass it the Book object for that row. This detail viewcontroller then just shows MORE info/fields from that same Book object.

Comment: yes, I do realize now that I just need one. I know how to make it so when you tap on a row you see more details. I just don't know how to make it so that you display different data using the same columns in different cells, using one detailviewcontroller.