# parse: check column then use data in that row

Tags: swift, parse-platform

[image]

Is it possible to check the Parse column **"ID"** for **0 (any number)** then if **0 (the one in the column)** equals `indexPath.row 0` (the first cell) it displays the data from the row of **0** in Parse? The picture above is the class for the viewcontroller, the tableview cell data is in another class.

**ID:** number that will be checked with the `indexPath.row`

**navTitle:** navigation bar title

**articleTitle:** UILabel

**written:** UILabel

**date:** UILabel

**article:** UITextView

**Edit for possible duplicate:** It is not a duplicate, the other question answers how to move data from a cell to a view controller using `prepareForSegue`. This question is asking how, if possible, to check a column on Parse and if a number in that column matches an `indexPath.row` it will use the data from that row to which the number corresponds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse: Retrieving Data by Row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34476435/parse-retrieving-data-by-row)

Answer (score 1):

I now understand you would like to show the data that is appropriate for a given index path in a detail view controller, after they tap on the cell at said index path. This is assuming you are correctly showing the appropriate data in the table view, and now the question is how to obtain and show the relevant data for the row the user tapped on in a new view controller.

To do this, you could add an internal property to your detail view controller that is an `Int`. Set this property to the table view's  selected index path's `row` before the detail view controller is shown, perhaps in `prepareForSegue` for example.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailViewController {
        if let selectedIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            detailVC.integerIdentifier = selectedIndexPath.row
        }
    }
}
```

Now in that detail view controller, you can access the property's value and query for the information you need from Parse given that value. (And you'll likely want to display some feedback to the user to inform them you're downloading the appropriate data to display.) For example, you could have the following code in a function you call from `viewDidLoad`:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "eventsDetail")
query.whereKey("ID", equalTo: self.integerIdentifier)
query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock { (detail: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    //update your labels etc using the detail (Optional) PFObject
}
```

I want to note, ***importantly***, that this is not a great way to store the data in Parse. One should not tie the data to how it will be displayed, which is the case here tying an identifier to the index path, forcing item with ID 0 to magically be the article details appropriate for the first cell in the table. You may wish to revisit the database design. For example, perhaps your other class that is used to generate a list of events could have a pointer to the event detail class, which would allow you to obtain the event details before you select an event and not have to query again for details.

**Original Answer:**
I understand you would like to show the data in this Parse class in your app in a table view, where the first table view cell displays the data for ID 0, the second cell displays the data for ID 1, etc.

To accomplish this, you'll want to query this class and apply an ascending order on the "ID" column. You will get back an array of PFObjects that are sorted as desired - lowest to highest ID, which you can use for your table view's data source to map them one-to-one.

Your query may look something like this:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Article")
query.orderByAscending("ID")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (articles: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    //use articles array as the data source, update the interface
    self.articles = articles
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Now in your table view data source methods, use this array to populate the table:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.articles.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let article = self.articles[indexPath.row]
    //... configure cell, show article title, etc, return cell
}
```

Comment: in the picture above, there are columns named: navTitle(title for navigation bar), articleTitle(UILabel), written(UILabel), date(UILabel), and article(UITextView). I actually want to display that data in UILabels, UITextViews, and NagivationBars. the tableview cells are all segued to one viewcontroller. the data for the cells and the data for the controller are different. the picture above is the class for the view controller, not the data for the cells. sorry if I didn't make that clear above, I will update it.

Comment: Not sure I'm following, can you show the class that contains the data for the cells?

Comment: the question isn't so much related toward the cells data. I want to be able to check if the `indexPath.row` is equal to the ID column on Parse and if so it will load data from that row to the view controller that all the cells are segued to. so if the `indexPath.row` is 0 which is the first cell, it checks the column ID on Parse for a 0 and when it matches it loads the data from row that has 0 as its ID to the viewcontrollers UILabels, navigation title, and UITextView.

Comment: @Hunter I see, I've updated the answer to explain how that can be done

Comment: so `query.whereKey("ID", equalTo: self.integerIdentifier)` checks the ID column, if I am correct. if you would, clarify how it checks the ID value and the `indexPath.row` values? still a bit confused on that part.

Comment: @Hunter correct. You have to pass the `indexPath.row` to the `integerIdentifier` property on the detail view controller. For example you could do this with `prepareForSegue` if you're using a storyboard segue. You can use `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()` to get it if needed.

Comment: could you put an example of `prepareForeSegue` in your answer? I think it would help me understand better and for anyone else who views this question later on.